# How to get precise division?

Tags: python, int, division, python-2.x, floating-point-precision

I'm trying to get precise division with Python without success.

`104101/2` gives `52050` whereas I need `52050.5`

I also tried `"%0.2f" % (104101/2)` which is giving me `'52050.00'`.

Javascript equivalent works. Any idea what's wrong with me?

Comment: What is [`0.1+0.2`](http://www.smbc-comics.com/?id=2999)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

104101/2.0

104101/float(2)

Or use Python 3